# Lags in game loop

Tags: java, game-loop

It's my game loop code:

```
public void run() {
    running = true;

    boolean renderCheck = false;
    double firstTime = 0;
    double lastTime = System.nanoTime() / 1000000000.0;
    double passedTime = 0;
    double unprocessedTime = 0;

    double frameTime = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    int fps = 0;

    while (running) {
        firstTime = System.nanoTime() / 1000000000.0;
        passedTime = firstTime - lastTime;
        lastTime = firstTime;

        unprocessedTime += passedTime;
        frameTime += passedTime;

        while (unprocessedTime >= UPDATE_CAP) {
            tick();
            unprocessedTime -= UPDATE_CAP;
            renderCheck = true;
        }

        if (frameTime >= 1.0) {
            frameTime = 0;
            fps = frames;
            frames = 0;
            System.out.println(fps);
        }

        if (renderCheck) {
            render();
            frames++;
            renderCheck = false;
        } else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's a render zone:

```
private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics graphics = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    graphics.setColor(Color.black);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    handler.render(graphics);

    graphics.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

And here is a tick part(it's not necessary to show other code for handler because it'll be so much to read):

```
private void tick() {
    handler.tick();
}
```

So the main problem is in the next thing. When i press the button my character has to start moving. And, actually, it does but with some delays which make this process look terrible. Than after a second, all is going perfectly. (I've already checked CPU loading - all goes normal)

This problem is happening only on linux PC. I've checked it on Windows 10 in exe format and all was working fine! That's a bit weird.

Comment: Not that I'm sure it would help, but have you considered running `tick()` and `render()` on different threads? Also how much time it takes from pressing a button press and game reaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo, finally i found a solution for fixing this issue!

Just set system properties to java2d in your static main method by writing this code:

```
public static void main(String argsp[]) {
    System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");
    new Game();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This lazy initialization might be your problem**:

```
private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    ...
```

Did you consider the fact on the first call of your `render()` function the `getBufferStrategy()` will return `null` at which point

- you will first create it (that is ok)
- then return without any action
  (that is suspicious)

*Subsequent calls of render would actually perform rendering ... later.* If you know for sure that you will need that bufferStrategy anyway, it would make sense to create it straight away when initializing your system.